# Modeling crumpling/vanishing 3D object

Tags: animation, cgi, 3d

I'd like to animate a **concave donut topology** object (coffee cup) as it **implodes**. The crumpling should be irregular - Like it's done by a hand or by vacuum implosion, not like a bellows compressing. It should preferably crumple in all three dimensions, but two dimensions (that is, the result is a line) would also be OK. How can I do this with a FOSS tool like Blender or OpenSCAD?

Comment: I don't know nearly enough about graphics to answer this, but now i can't stop thinking about coffee and doughnuts.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using OpenSCAD, though it is going to be very complex: not something for an OpenSCAD beginner to attempt.

You will need to manually draw the donut with [polyhedrons](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Primitive_Solids) and use OpenSCAD's View->animate option, and use the $t (time) variable to draw the donut crumpling over time.
The [animation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/The_OpenSCAD_Language#.24t) functionality in OpenSCAD isn't too well documented but you can find some examples just by visiting thingiverse.com and searching for "animate".

You can use OpenSCAD's rands function to make the implosion more irregular.

I would have posted more links, but I'm not allowed yet. At least the links I posted will get you to the user manual.

Answer (score 1):

Regular crumpling is easy in OPENScad:

```
difference(){
    cylinder(h=10+100*(1-$t), r=40*(1-$t));
    translate([0,0,10]) cylinder(h=10+90*(1-$t), r=33*(1-$t));
}
```

Try this with fps=25 and steps=100